# Getting Selectbox values from the database using PHP and mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I want to pick up peoples names from a phpmyadmin database and place them in a HTML select box, when the user picks a name from the select box it should display the detail from the database for that person in a table. I can't seem to get this to work, I can get the names to pick up from the database and display in a select box but when you click on the name it seems to bring up every record in the database rather than just the one for that person. I am using mysql rather than mysql. Here is my code

This is my back end stuff

```html
<?php 
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die ("No connection"); 
mysqli_select_db($conn, "flat") or die("db will not open"); 
$query = "select FlatCode, Address from FLAT"; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Invalid query"); 
echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>modulecode</th><th>studentnum</th></tr>";  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row[0] .  "</td><td>" .  $row[1] .  "</td></tr>";
} 
echo "</table>"; 
mysqli_close($conn); 
?>
```

this is my front end stuff

```html
<font size="4"> Choose an Owner Name</font><br><br> 
<form action="flat.php" method="post"> 
<select name="name"> 
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die ("No connection"); 
mysqli_select_db($con , "flat") or die ("db will not open"); 
$query = "SELECT distinct OwnerName, FlatCode, Address from FLAT"; 
/*$query= $_POST ("name")
function change_guery($query)
mysqli_use_result*/

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Invalid query");  
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{ 
      echo "<option value=\"" . $rows[0] . "\">" . $rows[0] . "</option>"; 
} 

echo "</select>"; 
        

mysqli_close($con); 
?> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit Value"> 
</form></body></html>
```

Comment: You mean the select box contains all database entries, not just the ones you want? That's because your query selects everything. `$query = "select FlatCode, Address from FLAT";` does not contain any `WHERE` clause, for example.

Comment: this doesn't work as i have already tried that

Comment: You commented out `$query= $_POST ("name")`. That's invalid syntax. It should be `$query= $_POST["name"];` with square brackets. However, I would change that to  `$name = $_POST["name"];` then do `$query = "SELECT distinct OwnerName, FlatCode, Address from FLAT WHERE column_x = '$name'";` as an example. `column_x` being the column you wish to query, as I don't know which one you want to use.

Comment: What have you tried? to include `WHERE`? Per what I can understand you want to have the flat/address for the user that is currently logged in or selected. So in your table `flat` you would have to have an identifier for the user. Then you need to query against that, for instance: `$query = "select FlatCode, Address from FLAT where userid='123' ";`

Comment: sadly this doesn't work

Comment: Add `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()` then, see if you're getting errors somewhere. Using `$con`, or `$conn` as your DB variable.

Comment: it display records okay, its just that it displays every record even ones not linked with that persons name

Comment: So what does your data base look like. And what does your query look like?

Comment: I think you have your front end stuff mixed up with your back end stuff. Your POST variable that you're trying to pass belongs in the back end, not the front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in your flat.php code. You are posting the the info correctly via form but you forgot to receive it via $_POST in flat.php.

See the following code and comments in it, it should work -

```
<?php 
$n = $_POST["name"];//we receive the name passed by the form
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die ("No connection"); 
mysqli_select_db($conn, "flat") or die("db will not open"); 
$query = "select FlatCode, Address from FLAT WHERE `OwnerName` = '$n' LIMIT 1";//see the changes here 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Invalid query"); 
echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>modulecode</th><th>studentnum</th></tr>";  
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
//as the result will return 1 row only so we dont need while loop here
echo "<tr><td>" . $row[0] .  "</td><td>" .  $row[1] .  "</td></tr>";
echo "</table>"; 
mysqli_free_result($result);//dont forget to free result
mysqli_close($conn); 
?>
```

Comment: sadly this still doesn't work, it's starting to stress me out

Comment: its meant to one row of the flat code, and address of each person who is picked from the select box

Comment: @Rebekah you mean like to select more than 1 person from that list and show the selected person(s) stats in flat.php?

Comment: no just one person should be selected but in flat.php it seems to display everything from the database

Comment: Use the exact code i gave in flat.php, note the changes in query line too, it should work properly. And does backend code = flat.php code in your question?

Comment: Yes it does but the code you gave me doesn't work it just makes a blank page appear

Comment: I just noticed that i put two closing bracket on mysqli_fetch_array line like this $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result **))** ; change this to $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result **)** ; and then try, maybe thats causing error.

Comment: haha I didn't even see that myself but thank you this has worked :-)